# $O(2^n)$ vs. $2^{O(n)}$

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function

The bound $2^{O(n)}$ seems to come up a lot, and I'm trying to get a feel for it.

If $f(n) = O(2^n)$ then there exist $n_0$ and $c>0$ such that $f(n) \le c2^n$ for all $n \ge n_0$.

If $g(n) = 2^{O(n)}$ then there exist $m_0$ and $d>0$ such that $\lg g(n) \le dn$ for all $n \ge m_0$.

So $g(n) \le 2^{dn}$ for all $n \ge m_0$.

If this is correct, how can we compare $f$ and $g$ above? I.e. what is "worse", $O(2^n)$ or $2^{O(n)}$? Is there any sort of intuition I should have about these bounds?

Comment: $2^{O(n)}$ is a broader class, which is sometimes worse and sometimes better than $O(2^n)$. Both $2^{n/2}$ and $2^{3n}$ grow like $2^{O(n)}$. The first grows much slower than $2^n$, while the second grows much faster.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I would say $2^{O(n)}$ is worse, because usually in this context we are looking for an upper bound and we think about the worst case in each class.  $f(n) = 2^{O(n)}$ is a weaker bound.

Comment: Instead of $2^{O(n)}$, I'd prefer to write $O(a^n)$ where $a$ can be arbirarily large (i..e, if we insist in viewing $O()$ as a set of functions, that is $\bigcup _{a>1}O(a^n)$). Then again, big-O notation has a tendency to sometimes trigger "colloquialisms"; note that $O(n^{1+\epsilon})$ is rather understood to mean $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}O(n^{1+\epsilon})$, so it may appear ambiguous whether a free parameter such as $a$ or $\epsilon$ should imply $\bigcup$ or $\bigcap$ ...

Comment: @MikeEarnest I always thought that Big-O classes are always in containment with one another, therefore in comparing one with another, one is always larger (i.e. worse) than the other. I may be mistaken, but if I am correct, *"sometimes worse and sometimes better"* sounds terribly misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to bound the growth rate of $f(n)$, the bound $f(n) = 2^{O(n)}$ is significantly worse than the bound $f(n) = O(2^n)$.  $O(2^n)$ is actually a set - the set of functions $f(n)$ so that there is a constant $M$ and an integer $n_0$ so that $f(n) < M \cdot 2^n$ for $n > n_0$.  Meanwhile, the set $2^{O(n)}$ is the set of functions $f(n)$ so that there exist $M, n_0$ and an $O(n)$ function $g(n)$ so that $f(n) < M \cdot 2^{g(n)}$ for $n > n_0$. The latter condition is weaker, since $g(n)$ could be $mn$ for any fixed $m$ which gives a bound $f(n) < M \cdot 2^{mn} = M \cdot (2^m)^n.$  So in the latter case, $f(n)$ could be $3^n$ or $100^n$ which grows asymptotically much faster.

It is true that $f(n) = 2^{O(n)}$ could mean that $f(n) = 2^{n/2}$, but $f(n)$ could also be $2^{n/2}$ if we know the sharper bound $f(n) = O(2^{n})$. Similarly some functions that are $O(n^2)$ grow asymptotically faster than some functions that are $O(n^3)$ (e.g., $n^2$ is $O(n^2)$ and $n$ is $O(n^3)$.)  But we still say that $O(n^3)$ is a worse bound than $O(n^2)$.

The language here is probably confusing, since we write $f(n) = O(g(n))$, by an accepted abuse of notation, to mean that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$.  Viewed as sets, it's clear that $2^{O(n)}$ is a strictly larger set than $O(2^n)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in the definition of $O(n)$ to compare between
$O(2^n)$ and $2^{O(n)}$. For example, $2^{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}2^n$, so clearly $2^{n-1}=O(2^n)$, and $2^{n/2}=2^{O(n)}$, but $2^{n/2}=o(2^{n-1})$. So in this example, $ 2^{O(n)}$ is much smaller than $O(2^n)$. On the other hand, $2^{4n}$ is $2^{O(n)}$ but $2^n=O(2^n)$ is much smaller than $2^{4n}$. Hence the two are incomparable.